# Convert string to integer ( binary equivalent )

Tags: c++, string, data-conversion

I have seen lots of ways to convert a string such as "12345" into an integer based on what the charecters represent ( the integer 12345 ) , but I need to be able to take a string's binary equivalent and turn *that* into an integer. For example , take the string "Hello!" . On the hard drive ( or memory ) it is stored as a binary pattern :

010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100001

If you treat these bits as a binary number instead of text, then that pattern is also equal to 79600447942433.

"Hello!" = 79600447942433

The only way I now of is to loop until the end of a string and convert individual charecters into integers, then multiply by 2^ position_of_charecter

```
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std ;
// ...
string str = "Hello!" ; int i , total , temp ; unsigned char letter ;
for ( i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++ )
{
    letter = string[ i ] ;
    temp = ( int ) letter ;
    total += ( temp * pow( 2 , i ) ) ;
}
cout << "\"Hello!\" is equal to " << total << endl ;
```

But I am working with very large strings and would like a faster way to convert it

Comment: You might want to check [`std::bitset<>`'s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) string conversion functions.

Comment: Your compiler supports 64-bit int types?  Your "total" variable in your code snippet is an int.

Comment: Your number does not match the binary, that is not even good. You may want to use pow(2,i*8), instead.

Comment: You say in your Question "I need to be able to take a strings binary equivalent and turn that into an Integer", but you code sample is is not converting a "0010001" string but a text string "Hello!", its not clear what you are after !!

Comment: @dampsquid "hello" seems to be the string input. He then convert each character into its binary equivalent based on the ascii codes of each letter... Or so it seems. It is those bits that are then used as an integer.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes I see what his code does ( or tries to do ), but he also mentions converting "12345" into 12345 in his question.

Comment: @dampsquid I believe he was just citing that as an example. He says he could see functions that convert string to int, if the string actually contains an int, think `atoi`   looks like just an example. Atoi wouldn't work here because he needs to take the letters in the string and convert them to bytes first... Is basically his point I believe. That part of his question can basically be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the std::bitset<> class.  See sample below.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<64> allBits("010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100001");
    cout << allBits.to_ullong();  // C++ 11.  If using earlier version, use to_ulong().
}
```

Note that the integer will need to fit within the maximum limit of an unsigned long if to_ulong() is used, and an unsigned long long if to_ullong() is used.

Comment: Where's the string of ASCII binary digits coming from?  The question looks like the input is text.

Answer (score 1):

First improvement: Replace `pow` and the associated conversions with a left shift (`<<`).